# Add text in between multiple plots

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I am plotting 5 rasters side by side. The figure represents a linear regression model, and so the plot should represent `r1 ~ r2 + r3 + r4 + r5`. I am using `par()` to line up the 5 rasters and would like to now add the text signs `~,+,+,+` on top in the white gaps.

Example of a multiplot:

```r
par(mfrow = c(1,5))
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
```

[image: Example with empty plots]

Desired outcome (example created in MS Paint):
[image: Desired example]

Comment: I really appreciate the effort of editing in Paint to make a clear example when you can't figure it out in your code. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `mtext` to write something into the margins of the plot:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,5))
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
mtext(side = 4, line = 1, "~", cex = 5, font = 2, las = 2)
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
mtext(side = 4, line = 4, "+", cex = 5, font = 2)
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
mtext(side = 4, line = 4, "+", cex = 5, font = 2)
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
mtext(side = 4, line = 4, "+", cex = 5, font = 2)
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
```

Here is the result
[image]

Note that `side = 4` refers to the right side of the plot. `las = 2` rotates the text by 90 degrees. `font = 2` refers to bold fonts.
If you want the text inbetween the plots even bigger you can choose `cex = 4` or even larger.

Comment: Can add `ann=FALSE` to `par(...)` in which case we can avoid `xlab="", ylab=""` in every plot statement.  The tricky part is that `las` does not affect labels in `plot` but does in `mtext`; otherwise, the `ylab` values could have been set.